# Batch Script Using 7zip: I want the zip files to have the name as the orignal file

Tags: batch, 7-zip

I have very little experience creating .bat files - I have several .bak files that I need to compress - this directory gets new .bak files dropped in regularly. I'm trying to setup a job that checks for any .bak files and zips them, I want to pass-through the .bak filename so that the .zip file has the same name as the .bak file.

So TestFile1.bak = TestFile1.zip, TestFile2.bak = TestFile2.zip ... etc

I have this so far and it works to zip a single file only, or it zips many .bak files into a single.zip file. I can't figure out how to pass-through the .bak filename.

7za a -tzip "C:\TestArchive\AutoArchived\" "C:\TestArchive*.*" -mx5

Answer (score 0):

What would help you, is the FOR command.

```
for /f "delims=#" %%i in ('dir /b *.bak') do ( 
  echo now working on file %%i
  rem use %%i in the 7zip command to compress only one file
)
```

This will loop all files returned by the dir command. With each loop %%i will contain one file which you could then use for your 7zip command.